# Two Equivalent definition of sepration

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

**Definition 1.**

Let  $ X $ be a metric space and let $ E \subseteq X. \{A,B\} $ is called separation of E if the following is true:

1. $ A \subseteq E $
2. $ B \subseteq E $
3. $ A \cup B = E $
4. $ \bar A \cap B = \emptyset = A \cap \bar B $

**Definition 2.**

Let  $ X $ be a metric space and let $ E \subseteq X. \{A,B\} $ is called separation of E if the following is true:

1. $ A, B $ are Open Sets
2. $ A \subseteq E $
3. $ B \subseteq E $
4. $ A \cup B = E $
5. $ A \cap B = \emptyset = A \cap B $

Could anyone suggest an idea why these two different definitions of separation are the same. I knew the first definition but in the solutions manual I found that the author proves $ E $ to be separated by using the second definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most easily done by working in the subspace $E$ with the relative topology that it inherits from $X$, so when I say that a set is open or closed, I mean that it is open or closed in that subspace topology. (Since the closures in the definition are in $X$, we do need the fact that $\operatorname{cl}_ES=E\cap\operatorname{cl}_XS$ for any $S\subseteq E$.) If $A$ and $B$ satisfy the second definition, then $A=E\setminus B$ and $B=E\setminus A$ are closed, so

$$A\cap\operatorname{cl}_EB=A\cap B=\varnothing=A\cap B=(\operatorname{cl}_EA)\cap B\;,$$

and we see that they satisfy the first definition as well.

Now suppose that $A$ and $B$ satisfy the first definition. We have $A=E\setminus\operatorname{cl}_EB$ and $B=E\setminus\operatorname{cl}_EA$, so $A$ and $B$ are open. Moreover, $A\cap B\subseteq A\cap\operatorname{cl}_EB=\varnothing$, so $A$ and $B$ satisfy the second definition.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I guess you wanted to Write $E$ instead of $ X $ right? And then I understand everything.

Comment: @G.T.: Actually, I misread the problem slightly. What I wrote has to be modified slightly to handle separations of arbitrary subsets of $X$, and I’ve now done that. You’re welcome.

Comment: One more clarification: Since $ A $ And $ B $ are both nonempty and subsets of $ E $, relative closure of B and A equal to their closures in $ X $ respectively right?

Comment: @G.T.: No, but they're the intersection with $E$ of the closures in $X$;  see the parenthetical remark in my first paragraph.